# Client boot default from WDS server not iPXE

Tags: wds, ipxe

The background information:
iPXE/DHCP Server: 192.168.0.5 Centos 7.9
WDS Server: 192.168.0.2 Windows 10

I instaled iPXE/ISC DHCP server in 192.168.0.5 and it works,also installed WDS Server in Windows 10, the issue is when I tryied install a new client that boot from network, default start WDS installation not iPXE.

I have setup iPXE menu and default from iPXE not WDS, if I stop WDS service and reboot client, it will be start from iPXE.

Don't know why.

Comment: What does your WDS server have as its **PXE Response** settings?

Comment: Hello Andrew,  how to check PXE Response settings as you said?

Comment: Are you sure this is iPXE and not just PXE?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, select "Do not listen on DHCP ports" in WDS server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I1H3.png)